# Right-click copy from selection without menu

Tags: python, tkinter, copy, right-click

I'm doing a small notepad for my work for security purposes. I'm not allowed to use menus in my software and I need to copy the things that I'm going to be typing in my notes. I was wondering how to copy things that I've selected with just a right click.

My script:

```
from tkinter import *

filename = None

def newFile():
    global filename
    filename = "Untitled"
    text.delete(0.0, END)

root = Tk() root.title("Comment Pad") root.minsize(width=520, height=600)
root.maxsize(width=520, height=600)

text = Text(root, width=400, height=400) text.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Something went wrong with your code formatting. Please try again.

Comment: FWIW, `0.0` is an invalid index. The first character is `1.0`. `0.0` merely works as a side effect of how it's implemented.

Answer (score -1):

Tkinter has commands for manipulating the clipboard: [clipboard_clear](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.clipboard_clear-method) and [clipboard_append](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.clipboard_append-method). You need to create a function to get the selected text and copy it to the clipboard, then set up a binding to call that function.

For example:

```
def copy_to_clipboard(self, event=None):
    try:
        sel = text.get("sel.first", "sel.last")
        root.clipboard_clear()
        root.clipboard_append(sel)
    except TclError:
        pass
text.bind("<ButtonRelease-3>", copy_to_clipboard)
```